# Whispir, callbacks api is not working

Tags: php, api, callback, whisper

Everyone using whispir API here?

I am trying to use their callback features however it is not working. according to their documentation http://developer.whispir.com/docs/read/Whispir_API_Callbacks callbacks are triggered by sending http request

```
HTTP 1.1 POST http://api.whispir.com/messages?apikey=<yourkey>
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/vnd.whispir.message-v1+xml
```

Please take note that I am using laravel 4.2

```
private static function curl_post($url, $username, $password, $curl_data)
        {
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 90,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 90,
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
                CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
                CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
                    'Authorization: Basic cGhwZGV2YWxwaGE6cGx1c3BsdXMxMjM=', 
                    'Content-Type: application/vnd.whispir.message-v1+json'
                ),
                CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13')",
                CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $curl_data,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 1,
                CURLOPT_USERPWD         => $username . ":" . $password
            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);     

            if(curl_errno($ch))
                  throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));

            curl_close($ch);

            return $data;
        }

        private static function sendMessage( $to, $subject, $body )
        {
            $host       = $_ENV['SMS_HOST'];
            $apikey     = $_ENV['SMS_APIKEY'];
            $username   = $_ENV['SMS_USERNAME'];
            $password   = $_ENV['SMS_PASSWORD'];

            $data = array(
                "to"            => $to,
                "subject"       => $subject,
                "body"          => $body,
                "callbackId"    => "callback"
            );

            $json = json_encode($data);
            return Smscenter::curl_post( $host.$apikey, $username, $password, $json );
        }
```

Please comment for any clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Whispir callbacks are triggered when a response occurs to a message that you've sent using the Whispir API.

So your code would send the message with a reference to which callback should be used, and any responses through Whispir will trigger this callback.

```
        $data = array(
            "to"            => $to,
            "subject"       => $subject,
            "body"          => $body,
            "callbackId"    => "callback"
        );
```

This code above is correct.  As long as in Whispir you have already configured a callback with a name of **callback**.

e.g.

[image: create a callback in whispir]

Once you've created the callback in Whispir, and sent an outbound message with this callbackId attached, any responses to this message will cause Whispir to fire a POST request to your URL.

The body of this request is as follows:

```
HTTP 1.1 POST http://mycallbackserver.com/mycallback
Content-Type: application/json
X-Whispir-Callback-Key: some-auth-code

{
    "messageId": "ABC4857BCCF484575FCA",
    "location" : "https://api.whispir.com/messages/ABC4857BCCF484575FCA",
    "from":{
        "name":"Fred Waters",
        "mri":"Fred_Waters.528798.Sandbox@Contact.whispir.com",
        "mobile":"04xxxxxxxx",
        "email":"test@test.com",
        "voice":"03xxxxxxxx"
     },
    "responseMessage":{
        "channel":"SMS",
        "acknowledged":"09/01/15 13:22",
        "content":"Yes, I accept. Will I need to bring steel cap boots?"
    }
}
```

Your application can catch this callback and parse it to get the responseMessage content.

This should have the callbacks up and running within your application.

**Notes:**

Firstly, I don't think you need to have the CURLOPT_USERPWD set if you are also providing the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER with the 'Authorization' parameter. They essentially do the same thing so I would opt for the CURLOPT_USERPWD option.

Second, as you've just broadcast your Authorization header, I would suggest both removing it from this post, and changing your password.

Lastly, I am the Product Manager for Whispir.io, so if you've got any other questions, please feel free to email them through to support@whispir.io and we can help you out.

Jordan